# Error #1064 con prepare en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy consultando info de phpmyadmin con la siguiente consulta:

```sql
SELECT alumnos.nombre, alumnos.apellidos, cursos.nombre_curso 
FROM alumnos, cursos 
WHERE alumnos.id = :idalumno 
AND cursos.id = :idcurso;
```

Pero me marca el siguiente error.

> #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca ':idalumno AND cursos.id = :idcurso LIMIT 0, 25' en la linea 1

Estructural de las tablas

```
Tabla: cursos
    id : int(255) AI PK 
    nombre_curso : varchar(255) 

Tabla: alumnos
    id : int(11) AI PK 
    nombre : varchar(255)
    apellidos : varchar(255) 

Tabla: alumnos_cursos
    id : int(11) PK 
    idalumno : int(255) 
    idcurso : int(255)
```

Este es el código donde está el fragmento de arriba.

```
$idcurso = isset($_GET['idcurso'])?$_GET['idcurso']:'';
$idalumno = isset($_GET['idalumno'])?$_GET['idalumno']:'';

$sql = "SELECT alumnos.nombre, alumnos.apellidos, cursos.nombre_curso 
    FROM alumnos, cursos 
    WHERE alumnos.id = :idalumno 
    AND cursos.id = :idcurso";
$consulta = $conexionBD->prepare($sql);
$consulta->bindParam(':idalumno',$idalumno);
$consulta->bindParam(':idcurso',$idcurso);
$consulta->execute();
$alumno = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($alumno);
```

Comment: En phpmyadmin, la consulta copiada directamente de php usando "prepare" no es válida, pues tienes que cambiar manualmente los valores de :idalumno y :idcurso por el valor que contiene la variable $idalumno y $idcurso

Comment: La info no es de PHPMyAdmin: PHPMyAdmin es una herramienta nada más. Tu base de datos puede que sea MySQL o MariaDB. Por otra parte, viendo [la documentación de bindParam](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php): ¿faltaría que coloques el tipo de dato? En los ejemplos de allí, tu caso es el primero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La consulta está equivocada. Estás comparando una columna en SQL contra un valor de referencia de PHP que no existe. Te hace falta una columna que hace de "llave foránea" o intermediaria entre las 2 tablas (`alumnos` y `cursos`).

Debido a que la tabla `cursos` debe ser una -entidad independiente- voy a asumir que en la tabla `alumnos` existe una columna que relaciona ambas tablas. Yo le llamaré `cursos_id`. Obvio, tu colócale como se llame en tu tabla.
**[!]** Si no tienes esa columna, entonces no podrás hacer la relación.

Luego de eso, la consulta quedará:

```php
$sql = "SELECT alumnos.nombre, alumnos.apellidos, cursos.nombre_curso 
    FROM alumnos, cursos 
    WHERE alumnos.cursos_id = cursos.id
    AND alumnos.id = :idalumno 
    AND cursos.id = :idcurso";
```

O escrito de una mejor manera (y la recomendada):

```php
$sql = "SELECT alumnos.nombre, alumnos.apellidos, cursos.nombre_curso 
    FROM alumnos 
    INNER JOIN cursos ON cursos.id=alumnos.cursos_id
    WHERE alumnos.id = :idalumno 
    AND cursos.id = :idcurso";
```

---

** Edit ** Se ha suministrado más información, incluyendo otra tabla que hace el cruce entre `alumnos` y `cursos`. En ese caso habría que incluirla en el join. Usé alias para que la consulta no quede tan larga.

```php
$sql = "SELECT A.nombre, A.apellidos, C.nombre_curso 
FROM alumnos A 
INNER JOIN alumnos_cursos T ON T.idalumno=A.id 
INNER JOIN cursos C on C.id=T.idcurso 
WHERE A.id = :idalumno 
AND C.id = :idcurso"
```

**Nota:** Verifica bien el nombre de tablas y columnas, en el comentario pusiste tabla `alumno` (en singular) pero en la pregunta está en plural. Yo asumí que está en plural.

Comment: Hola, @aeportugal gracias por la respuesta, he agregado el INNER JOIN pero ahora me manda el siguiente mensaje.

Warning: Undefined array key "nombre" in C:\desarrollo\xampp\htdocs\app\secciones\certificado.php on line 34

Te comento que si existe la tabla relacional llamada alumnos_cursos.

Quedo a la espera, gracias

Comment: @JonCode En ese caso parece hay una tabla intermediaria, lo cual requiere otro JOIN. Sugiero coloques en la pregunta la estructura de las 3 tablas, no tienen que ser todas las columnas, pero si las importantes.

Comment: te comparto:

Tabla "cursos" 
=> id : int(255) AI PK
=> nombre_curso : varchar(255)

Tabla "alumno"
=> id : int(11) AI PK
=> nombre : varchar(255)
=> apellidos : varchar(255)

Tabla relacional "alumnos_cursos"
=> id : int(11) PK
=> idalumno : int(255)
=> idcurso : int(255)

Gracias por el apoyo.

Comment: Ya le hice una modificación a la respuesta @JonCode Cuidado con los nombres de tablas y/o columnas, que no estás siendo consistente con ellos.